# List *.xyz files from a directory

Tags: python

Is there a built-in function in python, using I can list all *.xyz files from a directory?
If not, then how is it even possible to manage it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) module:

```
import glob
your_list = glob.glob('*.xyz')
```

**help** on `glob.glob`:

```
>>> print glob.glob.__doc__
Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.

    The pattern may contain simple shell-style wildcards a la
    fnmatch. However, unlike fnmatch, filenames starting with a
    dot are special cases that are not matched by '*' and '?'
    patterns.
```

Comment: or in `ipython`, `glob.glob?`

Answer (score 0):

One can use `glob` or `os` (I would like `glob` more)

```
from glob import glob
file_list = glob('*.xyz')
```

or

```
import os
file_list = [i for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if i.endswith('.xyz')]
```

Using `glob` allows You not to filter result yourself but custom filterring allow to check complex rules

also One should remember that `filenames starting with a dot are special cases that are not matched by '*' and '?' patterns.`